# Join Null Values

Tags: join

I have two tables and I need all the rows from both the tables, I used the full outer join but not getting the exact rows I am looking for any help.

```
Table A
PlaceID  Name  Date
A        Angle   11/11/2012
B        Ball    1/5/2014
C        Car     6/7/2014 
D        Doll     9/8/2015

Table B
PlaceID     Status   Count
A           Run       90
B           Run       120
C           Run       110
            Deploy    145
```

I need the Output as

```
PlaceID     Status      Count
A           RUN          90
B           RUN          120
C           RUN          110
D
            DEPLOY       145
```

Help Really appreciated.

Thank you
Jagan

Comment: What's the query you ran and what's the output? Please share

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I haven't tested it, but I know from experience (Oracle's) `nvl` function can be useful with nulls.

```
Select TableA.PlaceID, TableB.Status, TableB.Count
From A TableA Full Outer Join B TableB on
    nvl(TableA.PlaceID, '-1') = nvl(TableB.PlaceID, '-2');
```